pylint invalid-name warning for override methods
I have a Python (3.12.3) script that uses PyQt6 to make a simple GUI. pylint returns the following warning:
C0103: Method name "paintEvent" doesn't conform to snake_case naming style (invalid-name)

This method is an override (even has the @override decoration from typing), so I have no choice in the naming convention. I can add pylint: disable=invalid-name to this function, however, that disables that warning for the function definition as well, which is undesirable.
Is there a way to prevent that warning for override methods?
